# Accessing Google API (Calendar) from the command line

Tags: curl, oauth, google-api

How can I retrieve calendar events from *my* Google account (multiple calendars, but I only care about ones shared with my account) *from the command line with curl*?  That is, the `curl` command, not PHP or any other language library. I don't want a library. I don't want anything that requires me to be running a web server somewhere that OAuth can make requests to.  I would just like to know what sequence of actual HTTP(S) calls will enable me to type a command at my terminal window and get calendar events back on stdout and not have to open a browser at any point.

Is this doable?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I noticed this was tagged with `oauth` - are you looking to use oauth, or any method possible?

Comment: I got the impression that oauth was a requirement to interact with the Google API.  Is that not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

- Register an OAuth 2.0 client and get a refresh token for [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) - you can use something like https://oauth2-client-shell.herokuapp.com/ (disclaimer: I'm the primary contributor to `oauth2-client-shell`) to go through the authorization flow. You can use the refresh token to get access tokens via `curl`, and make REST calls in `curl` with the access tokens.
- Simulate a login somehow in the CLI (e.g. do the login POST yourself), keeping track of your cookies between calls

Comment: Yeah,I found a guide to the refresh token thing and have been working through it with the intent of turning it into an answer.  Thanks!